# If I use a while loop to iterate through the contents of a pointer to an array, how do I return back to the first element in the array?

Tags: c, pointers

Say for example I have a function called from main that returns a pointer:

**EDIT**
: I was a little unclear, sorry! Let's say I used a scanf in the main() and then I passed this into the function, and I wanted to copy the argument into a new pointer then return that one.

```
main(void)
{
   char *word = malloc(50);

   scanf("%s", word);

   printf("%s", function(word));
}

char *function(char *array)
{
    char *a = malloc(50);
    while (*array)
    {
        *a = *array;
        a++;
        array++;
    }
return a;
}
```

In this case, if I tried to return the pointer array to main, the pointer would be pointing to the memory location 1 space past where my values are held.

How would I make so I can return the pointer to the first value again?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a temporary variable?

Comment: If I do `int i = rand() % 10; while(i < 50) i++; return i;`, how can I return the original random number instead of 50?

Comment: Just to be clear: are you trying to implement memcpy()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to not increment your pointers at all:

```
char *function(char *array)
{
    const size_t maxLength = 49;

    char * a = malloc(maxLength + 1);
    if ( !a ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t i;
    for ( i = 0; array[i] && i < maxLength; ++i ) {
        a[i] = array[i];
    }
    a[i] = '\0';

    return a;
}
```

Your original code does not null-terminate `a`, yet you pass it to `printf()` as if it's a string. Also, you're leaking memory, since you don't store the pointer you're returning, so you can never `free()` it.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared up a lot for me. What would be the difference if I used int instead of size_t for 'i'?

Comment: @KelvinChan: If you're allocating a very large amount of memory, you might find that `int` isn't large enough, where `size_t` is. Other than that, there's no real difference.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is to use a temporary variable to hold the pointer value you want to keep.

Assuming the only one you care about in your example is `a`.

```
char *function(char *array)
{
    char *a, *t;
    t = a = malloc(50);
    while (*array)
    {
         *t = *array;
         ++t;
         ++array;
    }
    *t = '\0';   /* since the caller passes returned pointer to printf() */

    return a;    /*  a unchanged, so return it */
}
```

Note that the above will have undefined behaviour if `strlen(array) >= 50`.

In your example, `array` is passed by value, so changes to it (repeated incrementing) do not propagate to the caller - there is no need to reset `array` back to its original value.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to not use the parameter to the function, but a copy of it inside the function.

```
char* pTmp = array;
```

Also it's better to do ++pTmp rather than array++ because for non-POD types it can be quicker.

Comment: This is C, not C++. There are no "non-POD types" you can increment in this way.

Comment: The whole `POD` types is `C++` fufu because in `C` everything is `POD` [i.e. it's "Back To The Future" for c++ :-)].  I also use `++x` because [IMO] it's clearer as to intent